# How do I escape question mark with nginx rewrite?

Tags: nginx, migration, url-rewriting

Im bussy migrating my websites to nginx and I have a lot of rewrite rules that need to be converted, the only problem I'm experiencing is when I try to do something like this:

```
rewrite ^/media?(.*)$                   /in.php?id=$1                   last;
```

This causes php to read $1 ad the key of $_GET instead of it's value. Is there any way to change this behaviour without resorting to difficult location based methods? The reason I'm asking is because I have multiple query string based rewrites that need to be addressed.

Comment: Do you want to pass to `in.php` query value from `media`, yes? For example rewrites `/metdia?hello=3` as `/in.php?id=3`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. For example: /media?123 should translate to /in.php?id=123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything what comes after `?` in nginx is known as variable `$query_string`, so if you want to translate whole query string from location rule `^/media?(.*)$`, because it looks like it's what you want, try to use this:

```
rewrite ^/media?(.*)$   /in.php?id=$query_string   last;
```

Is it what are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry, one final question, how would this work:`rewrite ^/search\?q=(.*)&p=([0-9]+)$      /search.php?q=$1&p=$2       last;`

Comment: If you change it to `^/search\?q=([^&]*)&p=([0-9]+)$` it's possible that it will work as you expected because `[^&]` means any character other than `&` and in your rule I'm not sure that if someone type `/search?q=898989kjaf&p=894` then `898989kjaf&p=894` can goes as `$1`

Comment: one more thing - it is possible that nginx will append original query string (in `$query_string` variable) after your query string. To change this just use this directive `set $args "";`. `$query_string` is unchangeable during request processing but it's actual value which is append to final request nginx stores in `$args` variable. When you want to discard initial query string and pass only your own just set `$args` to empty string with `set` directive.